# Bar graph is upside down

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox, drawrectangle

I'm trying to make a bar graph from an array and it works. The only problem is that it's upside down.

[image]

This is the code i have now:

```
            int widthCalc = pbxGraph.Width / days;

            for (int i = 0; i < speedPoints.Length; i++)
            {
                float height = distanceGraph[i] * 110;
                Rectangle barGraph = new Rectangle(i*(widthCalc/3), 150, 10, (int)height);
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, barGraph);
            }
            pen.Color = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: You could Translate and Scale the Graphics object if you want to use normal, non-gdi coordinates, but I'm not sure it would be a really better way. To do so you would need to know the size your daring surface is supposed to have..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rectangles are defined as the top x, top y, width, and height.
Subtract the height from your second Rectangle argument.

```
new Rectangle(i*(widthCalc/3), 150 - (int)height ...);
```